# aggregation result give full table json instead count result in mongo node driver

Tags: mongodb

I have a doc with a single row that I update(replace the list with a new list in each update):

then I need to check if the item in the list and get the count number

when I trying to get count number with mongo drive node.js I got the doc itself  instead of the projection

```
result

{
  _id : 23432424,
  nane:: "test",
  list : ["1","2"....."500"]
}



   result = await db.collection.aggregate( { $project: {name:1, count: {$size: "$list"}}})
console.log(result.toArray())
```

when I run in client or from mongo NoSQL booster software I got

```
{
   _id:....,
    name:"test",
    count: 500 

}
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution 
in node mongo driver we should use .project() instead projection object as follows:

```
aggregate({}).project({ count: {$size: '$list'}})
```